# Differential Mode EMI Filter Position

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, filter, emc, emi-filtering

In the AC input power supplies; input EMI filters(common + differential) are connected between mains and the rectifier. In some low power power supplies; **only differential mode filter** is used and this filter is used **after the rectifier**. What's the reson behind that?

Examples:
[image]

[image]

Comment: The purpose of those filters is somewhat different. The top schematic shows a **common mode filter** which is needed to prevent the high frequency switching noise (generated by fast switching inside the flyback converter) from "escaping" into the mains connection as that would result in large EMI emissions. The bottom schematic is a filter that is **ground referenced** and used to supply a **clean supply voltage** to the VIPER011LS chip.

Comment: The two pictures cannot be compared. The first picture seems to be schematics of an actual product. The second picture looks like block diagram from chip marketing material to approximately show kind of building blocks the chip needs around it, so it is certainly not a finished product you could manufacture and sell.